# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value swift

Tags: swift, ios8

Ok so I am trying to run this code but I keep on getting this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I don't understand what it means or why im getting it. Can someone please help me. Thanks

```
query.whereKey("accepted", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
query.whereKey("username", containedIn: PFUser.currentUser()["accepted"] as [AnyObject])
```

Comment: This means that the program is receiving nil value for a optional variable. Please check for nil and then do the next operation. I am guessing "PFUser.currentUser()" might be returning nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is this:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    query.whereKey("accepted", equalTo: currentUser.username)
    if let someArrayObject = currentUser["accepted"] as? [AnyObject] {
        query.whereKey("username", containedIn: someArrayObject)
    }
} else {
    // currentUser does not exist, do error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to objective-c documentation of [PFUser.currentUser()](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/currentUser), which I'm assuming translates into a Swift optional, it could easily return nil. So you need to do something like:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    query.whereKey("accepted", equalTo: currentUser.username)
    if let someArrayObject = currentUser["accepted"] as? [AnyObject] {
        query.whereKey("username", containedIn: someArrayObject)
    }
} else {
    // currentUser does not exist, do error handling
}
```

Not sure what that second `query` line is, and what the `someArrayObject` is, so you might look further into that. But your error is either related to you dereferencing the `currentUser()` which could be nil, or the use of `as` and not `as?` in the second `query` line.

Solution to either is to use proper unwrapping of the potential optional values.